# dynamic_cast vs exposing virtual functions in parent class (C++)

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have a parent class "base" and another class "derived" that inherits from "base".

"derived" has 1 method cH1.

if I do this:

```
base* b = new derived();
```

And I want to be able to do this:

```
b->cH1();
```

Obviously I can't and there are 2 solutions:

- Either declare cH1 as pure virtual in base.
- or do this:

  ```
  dynamic_cast<derived*>(b)->cH1();
  ```

Which one is a better practice?

Comment: Please turn off you caps-lock key; `PARENT` suggests that the name is a macro; `parent` is the usual usage.

Comment: I'd say that the biggest problem in your head may be the use of the words "parent" and "child". Those are *really terrible* metaphors for base- and derived classes: A child, in common parlance, is not usually a parent, nor is it a more specific instance of a parent. A much better metaphor is "base class" and "derived class".

Comment: @PeteBecker and @KerrekSB: good suggestions. Moreover, I'd suggest to change `cH1` (kind of obscure and odd for a generic method name) to something like `m1` or `method1`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200446/does-downcasting-defeat-the-purpose-of-polymorphism

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `cH1` method semantically applies to `base`, then make it a `base`'s method.
Else, leave `cH1` to `derived`, and use `dynamic_cast`.
I think the *semantics* of your classes should drive your choice.

For example, if you have a base class `Vehicle` and derived classes `Car`, `Motorbike`, and `Aircraft`, a method like `TakeOff()` has a semantics compatible with `Aircraft` but not with `Car` or `Motorbike`, so you may want to make `TakeOff()` an `Aircraft` method, not a `Vehicle` method.

Comment: I keep hearing this word and I never understood it :/
what do you mean by "semantically" applies to base?

Comment: @Kam: For example, if you have a base class `Vehicle` and derived classes `Car`, `Motorbike`, and `Aircraft`, a method like `TakeOff()` has a semantics compatible with `Aircraft` but not with `Car` or `Motorbike`, so you may want to make `TakeOff()` an `Aircraft` method, not a `Vehicle` method.

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` is cleaner and more flexible, but a bit slower.

Remember when you use `dynamic_cast` to check the returned pointer for NULL.

Comment: How is `dynamic_cast` cleaner and more flexible?  There are cases where `dynamic_cast` may be justified, but from the information given, I don't think we can conclude that this is one of them.  (In general, the use of virtual functions is cleaner.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, it's cleaner if the parent class isn't being cluttered with functions which aren't relevant to that class. I agree that we need more information of the class specifics to really know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

First, in order to use `dynamic_cast`, `base` must have at least one virtual function.

Second, use of `dynamic_cast` is **usually** a sign of a design mistake. If `derived` is truly a child of `base`, then a `derived` object should be able to stand in wherever a `base` object is expected, and that usually means that `base` has virtual functions, either pure virtual or not, and that `derived` overrides some or all of them.

Without knowing what `cH1` does, though, it's impossible to recommend an approach.

Comment: It's not always a mistake - sometimes you need a collection of objects which have some things in common but not others.

Comment: Use of `dynamic_cast` to the concrete class is almost always a mistake, but it's not that rare for a class (or a group of classes) to support an extended interface.  In such cases, `dynamic_cast` is one way of supporting access to the extended interface.

Comment: I've added emphasis to the word **usually**, since it seems to have been overlooked. I didn't say it's always a mistake.